# How to load multiple images in wxPython?

Tags: python, image, wxpython

I've been struggling with how to load multiple images from a folder using wxFileDialog and then add those pictures to an array. Here is the code:

```
def loadImages(self, e):
    wildcard = 'JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|' +\
               'PNG files (*.png)|*.png|' +\
               'Other files (*.*)|*.*'
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose images", 
                        wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_MULTIPLE)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.imageName = dlg.GetFilename()
        self.directory = dlg.GetDirectory()
        self.image = self.directory + '/' + self.imageName
    for dlg in dlg.GetPaths():
        image = Image.open(dlg)
        self.imagesA = np.append(self.imagesA, image)
dlg.Destroy()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Getting the file list from the dialog, getting the pixel values from the image or storing them in the numpy array. Incidently, how is `self.imagesA` initially defined?

Comment: I’m struggling with choosing the images from the folder and putting them into an array so I can take a median value out of them. @RolfofSaxony

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific and the median value of what?

Comment: i want to be able to load images from the computer and then use those images for whatever my software does. Basically, I don't understand how to select multiple images and load them onto my app so I can use my inpainting algorithm on it. @RolfofSaxony